# Can not make this image slider work in multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have this simple image slider, the function for it looks like this:

```
function slider(pocket, time){      
$(pocket).find('> div:first').addClass('sn');
var nos = $(pocket).find('> div').length;
var timer = null;
    function fadeNext() {
    var currentSlide = $(pocket).find('> div.sn');
    var nextSlide = $(currentSlide).next('div');
    if(nextSlide.length == 0){
        nextSlide = $(pocket).find('> div:first');
    }
        $(currentSlide).removeClass('sn').fadeOut(time);
        $(nextSlide).addClass('sn').fadeIn(time);
    }
    function fadePrev() {
    var currSlide = $(pocket).find('> div.sn');
    var prevSlide = $(currSlide).prev('div');
    if(prevSlide.length == 0){
        prevSlide = $(pocket).find('> div:last');
    }
        $(currSlide).removeClass('sn').fadeOut(time);
        $(prevSlide).addClass('sn').fadeIn(time);
    }
$(pocket).find('.sl_next').on('click',  function() {
    fadeNext();
});
$(pocket).find('.sl_prev').on('click',  function() {
    fadePrev();
});

function startSlide(){
    timer = setInterval(fadeNext, 3999);
}

if(time > 0 && nos > 1){
    startSlide();
}   
}
```

Then I call the function like this:

```
slider('.manual', 0);
slider('.auto', 500);
```

..and here is the problem; I have multiple sets of images, the ones with class ".manual" have 'previous' and 'next' buttons. and the ones with class "auto" are to automatically rotate between images.

I have different number of images in each set, for example I have 2, 3, 5 images in 3 sets with class ".auto". The slider would work well at first then the set with 2 and 3 images will just be blank(all images will stay 'display:none') till the set with 5 images reach the last image, instead of getting back to the first image after they reach their respective last image.

So In the end only the set with maximum images and manual sets look normal, and I think I need help! Thank you!

Comment: Please add the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, I tried to remove as much function as I could and just keep the core functions, I need help with. You can see just as much to work with a manual and automatic slider.
I will try to make it more short, I am not very experienced. Sorry about lot of codes I used, and your time, and thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: In this case, it's not a matter of making it shorter but complete. Right now you are only displaying the JS but don't show how the HTML or the CSS is done. It took me a while to make a simple demo to reproduce the error ([here if someone is interested](http://jsfiddle.net/3n0d54t3/), although it may not be accurate). Solving an issue is already a thing, don't make it more complicated by having the users guessing what your code looks like or how to reproduce the errors. Summarizing: help people help you :)

Comment: Got it. I am totally clear about it now. Thank you very much for making the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `$(pocket)` inside the `fadeNext()` and `fadePrev()` methods. That works great if there is only one element selected by `$(pocket)` but if there are multiple, then things get wrong because you are counting all `div`s inside all the pockets.

One possible solution: inside the `fadeNext()` and `fadePrev()` methods, **traverse each "pocket" individually** by using the `each()` function (you will need to update all the reference to pocket inside it, and replace them with `this`). That way, you will only count the `div`s inside that particular pocket instead of counting all the `div`s in all the pockets.

Something like this:

```
function slider(pocket, time){      
    $(pocket).find('> div:first').addClass('sn');
    var nos = $(pocket).find('> div').length;
    var timer = null;
    function fadeNext() {
        $(pocket).each(function() {
            var currentSlide = $(this).find('> div.sn');
            var nextSlide = $(currentSlide).next('div');
            if(nextSlide.length == 0){
                nextSlide = $(this).find('> div:first');
            }
            $(currentSlide).removeClass('sn').fadeOut(time);
            $(nextSlide).addClass('sn').fadeIn(time);
        });
    }
    function fadePrev() {
        $(pocket).each(function() {
            var currSlide = $(this).find('> div.sn');
            var prevSlide = $(currSlide).prev('div');
            if(prevSlide.length == 0){
                prevSlide = $(this).find('> div:last');
            }
            $(currSlide).removeClass('sn').fadeOut(time);
            $(prevSlide).addClass('sn').fadeIn(time);
        });
    }
    $(pocket).find('.sl_next').on('click',  function() {
        fadeNext();
    });
    $(pocket).find('.sl_prev').on('click',  function() {
        fadePrev();
    });

    function startSlide(){
        timer = setInterval(fadeNext, 3999);
    }

    if(time > 0 && nos > 1){
        startSlide();
    }   
}

slider('.manual', 0);
slider('.auto', 500);
```

You can see a working demo on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3n0d54t3/1/

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, I think I understand my mistakes now.
The solution actually works perfectly well in my case. Sorry about not making the question complete, and thank you for the time. 

Stay safe!

Comment: Sorry my explanation is not that great, at least you figured it out and it worked for you. Have a nice weekend :)